# ! File ended while scanning use of \entry

Tags: errors, badness

I am a newbie trying to compile Friggeri's resume template using XeLaTeX. The attached file compiled perfectly on first couple of occasions. However, I continued to make some changes to the content and now it throws the following error:

```
* Package hyperref Warning: Rerun to get /PageLabels entry.


Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 59--80

) Runaway argument? {\emph {Marcom Coordinator} \\ Conceptualized and
strategized marketi\ETC. ! File ended while scanning use of \entry.
<inserted text> 
                \par  <*> Resume.tex*
```

I deleted the `.aux` files and tried to compile but ended up with the same error.

Can anyone please help me debug?

The template can be accessed here.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2VMbfmQccpVdWZnaVN0Yk5jaGs/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please help us helping you and produce an MWE. This is a minimal code which contains only lines which reproduce your error. Make a copy of your code and delete all lines, which are not of interest and all packages which do not influence here. We do not debug here, but give help on single problems. First, you have to locate that problem. Thanks.

Comment: the brace group started by `{\emph {Marcom` doesn't have a matching `}`

Comment: Thanks @LaRiFaRi, will keep that in mind going forward rather than attaching the entire code template.
Thanks DavidCarlisle :) I have closed the brace now. 
However, I have a new error:
*? 
! Missing } inserted.
<inserted text> 
                }
l.104 \end{itemize}}*

The line in question is the last line of the following snippet:
{\emph{Marcom Coordinator} \\
..
Detailed achievements:
\begin{itemize}
\item (..)
.
.
.
\end{itemize}}
The open & close braces count match so I am not sure where it is missing :( Pointers please.
Many thanks for your help

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Do you wanna take any action here?